# mongodb aggregation framework group + project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following issue:

this query return 1 result which is what I want:

```
> db.items.aggregate([ {$group: { "_id": "$id", version: { $max: "$version" } } }])

{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "b91e51e9-6317-4030-a9a6-e7f71d0f2161",
        "version" : 1.2000000000000002
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

this query ( I just added projection so I can later query for the entire document) return multiple results. What am I doing wrong?

```
> db.items.aggregate([ {$group: { "_id": "$id", version: { $max: "$version" } }, $project: { _id : 1 } }])

  {
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5139310a3899d457ee000003")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("513931053899d457ee000002")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("513930fd3899d457ee000001")
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

found the answer

#### 1. first I need to get all the _ids

```
db.items.aggregate( [ 
  { '$match': { 'owner.id': '9e748c81-0f71-4eda-a710-576314ef3fa' } },
  { '$group': { _id: '$item.id', dbid: { $max: "$_id" } } } 
]);
```

#### 2. then i need to query the documents

```
db.items.find({ _id: { '$in': "IDs returned from aggregate" } });
```

which will look like this:

```
db.items.find({ _id: { '$in': [ '1', '2', '3' ] } });
```

Answer (score 0):

( *I know its late but still answering it so that other people don't have to go search for the right answer somewhere else* )

See to the [answer of Deka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739662/4394926), this will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Not all accumulators are available in `$project` stage. We need to consider what we can do in project with respect to accumulators and what we can do in group. Let's take a look at this:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    funding_rounds: {
      $ne: []
    }
  }
}, {
  $unwind: "$funding_rounds"
}, {
  $sort: {
    "funding_rounds.funded_year": 1,
    "funding_rounds.funded_month": 1,
    "funding_rounds.funded_day": 1
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: {
      company: "$name"
    },
    funding: {
      $push: {
        amount: "$funding_rounds.raised_amount",
        year: "$funding_rounds.funded_year"
      }
    }
  }
}, ]).pretty()
```

[image: $group in MongoDB]

Where we're checking if any of the `funding_rounds` is not empty. Then it's `unwind`-ed to `$sort` and to later stages. We'll see one document for each element of the `funding_rounds` array for every company. So, the first thing we're going to do here is to `$sort` based on:

1. `funding_rounds.funded_year`
2. `funding_rounds.funded_month`
3. `funding_rounds.funded_day`

In the group stage by company name, the array is getting built using `$push`. `$push` is supposed to be part of a document specified as the value for a field we name in a group stage. We can push on any valid expression. In this case, we're pushing on documents to this array and for every document that we push it's being added to the end of the array that we're accumulating. In this case, we're pushing on documents that are built from the `raised_amount` and `funded_year`. So, the `$group` stage is a stream of documents that have an `_id` where we're specifying the company name.

Notice that `$push` is available in `$group` stages but not in `$project` stage. This is because `$group` stages are designed to take a sequence of documents and accumulate values based on that stream of documents.

`$project` on the other hand, works with one document at a time. So, we can calculate an average on an array within an individual document inside a project stage. But doing something like this where one at a time, we're seeing documents and for every document, it passes through the group stage pushing on a new value, well that's something that the `$project` stage is just not designed to do. For that type of operation we want to use `$group`.

Let's take a look at another example:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    funding_rounds: {
      $exists: true,
      $ne: []
    }
  }
}, {
  $unwind: "$funding_rounds"
}, {
  $sort: {
    "funding_rounds.funded_year": 1,
    "funding_rounds.funded_month": 1,
    "funding_rounds.funded_day": 1
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: {
      company: "$name"
    },
    first_round: {
      $first: "$funding_rounds"
    },
    last_round: {
      $last: "$funding_rounds"
    },
    num_rounds: {
      $sum: 1
    },
    total_raised: {
      $sum: "$funding_rounds.raised_amount"
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    company: "$_id.company",
    first_round: {
      amount: "$first_round.raised_amount",
      article: "$first_round.source_url",
      year: "$first_round.funded_year"
    },
    last_round: {
      amount: "$last_round.raised_amount",
      article: "$last_round.source_url",
      year: "$last_round.funded_year"
    },
    num_rounds: 1,
    total_raised: 1,
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    total_raised: -1
  }
}]).pretty()
```

[image: group vs project in MongoDB]

In the `$group` stage, we're using `$first` and `$last` accumulators. Right, again we can see that as with `$push` - we can't use `$first` and `$last` in project stages. Because again, project stages are not designed to accumulate values based on multiple documents. Rather they're designed to reshape documents one at a time. Total number of rounds is calculated using the `$sum` operator. The value **1** simply counts the number of documents passed through that group together with each document that matches or is grouped under a given `_id` value. The project may seem complex, but it's just making the output pretty. It's just that it's including `num_rounds` and `total_raised` from the previous document.