# Include all existing fields and add new fields to document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to define a $project aggregation stage where I can instruct it to add a new field and include all existing fields, without having to list all the existing fields.

My document looks like this, with many fields:

```json
{
    obj: {
        obj_field1: "hi",
        obj_field2: "hi2"
    },
    field1: "a",
    field2: "b",
    ...
    field26: "z"
}
```

I want to make an aggregation operation like this:

```json
[
    {
        $project: {
            custom_field: "$obj.obj_field1",
            //the next part is that I don't want to do
            field1: 1,
            field2: 1,
            ...
            field26: 1
        }
    },
    ... //group, match, and whatever...
]
```

Is there something like an "include all fields" keyword that I can use in this case, or some other way to avoid having to list every field separately?

Comment: This feature is coming in the next major release 2.6.  You can try it on the unstable dev branch - use "$$ROOT" to refer to the entire incoming document.  See details in this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5916

Comment: This issue is also raised at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497499/mongodb-project-retain-previous-pipeline-fields, with some other useful and different answers.

Answer (score 243):

In 4.2+, you can use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) aggregation pipeline operator which is nothing other than an alias to [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)added in 3.4

> The `$addFields` stage is equivalent to a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { "custom_field": "$obj.obj_field1" } }
])
```

Comment: Any idea how to use it in C# driver? seems it does not exist

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C# driver but `$addFields` is new in MongoDB 3.4 which is supported by the [C# driver version 2.5+](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/#mongodb-compatibility)

Comment: I have been searching for a way to do this in C# driver, and so far it looks like the way to do it would be using something like `IAggregateFluent<TResult>.AppendStage(new JsonPipelineStageDefinition<TInput, TOutput>("{ $addFields : { myField: 'myValue' }}")`

Comment: I discovered that it can even replace a field if you specify the same field name

Answer (score 95):

You can use [$$ROOT](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) to references the root document. Keep all fields of this document in a field and try to get it after that (depending on your client system: Java, C++, ...)

```
 [
    {
        $project: {
            custom_field: "$obj.obj_field1",
            document: "$$ROOT"

        }
    },
    ... //group, match, and whatever...
]
```

Comment: But this will create an embedded doc called `document` an option to created one merged doc would have been nicer...

Comment: Does anyone know of the solution to pass through all the key value pairs without creating the embedded document?

Comment: Hold your breath. MongoDB 3.4 will come with [$addFields aggregation stage](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5781) that does just this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24557029/4653485.

Comment: This seems to be the best current solution, as you can (at least in JS) then use the spread operator to rebuild your original object with the new `custom_field` attached. `const newObj = { ...result.document, custom_field: result.custom_field }`

Answer (score 10):

To add new fields to your document you can use `$addFields`

[from docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-title-by-author)

and to all the fields in your document, you can use  `$$ROOT`

```
db.collection.aggregate([

{ "$addFields": { "custom_field": "$obj.obj_field1" } },
{ "$group": {
        _id : "$field1",
        data: { $push : "$$ROOT" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: He wants all fields in root. This adds all fields under documents array.

Answer (score 8):

*>>> There's something like "include all fields" keyword that I can use in this case or some another solution?*

Unfortunaly, there is no operator to "include all fields" in aggregation operation. The only reason, why, because aggregation is mostly created to group/calculate data from collection fields (sum, avg, etc.) and return all the collection's fields is not direct purpose.

Comment: *...because aggregation is mostly created to group/calculate data from collection fields...* Best answer in fact!

Comment: you have a collection `posts` with _id, title, body, likes fields. The likes field is an array of user _id who like the post. How could you list all posts with all the _id, title, body, likeCount? Returning all fields is a direct purpose in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.6.4, Mongo DB does not have such a feature for the `$project` aggregation pipeline. From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) for `$project`:

> Passes along the documents with only the specified fields to the next stage in the pipeline. The specified fields can be existing fields from the input documents or newly computed fields.

and

> The _id field is, by default, included in the output documents. To include the other fields from the input documents in the output documents, you must explicitly specify the inclusion in $project.

Answer (score 0):

according to @Deka reply, for c# mongodb driver 2.5 you can get the grouped document with all keys like below;

```
var group = new BsonDocument
{
 { "_id", "$groupField" },
 { "_document", new BsonDocument { { "$first", "$$ROOT" } } }
};

ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> projection = new BsonDocument{{ "document", "$_document"}};
var result = await col.Aggregate().Group(group).Project(projection).ToListAsync();

// For demo first record 
var fistItemAsT = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(result.ToArray()[0]["document"].AsBsonDocument);
```