# Add a field to $project pipeline in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I just want to add a new field through `$project` pipeline and let the other properties to slip through for further processing, I know that you can do this :

```
db.people.aggregate([
     {$project: {name: 1, address: 1, birth_month: {$month: "$birthdate"}}}
])
```

But with more and more complex document, I have a great difficulty to write 20++  field name in `$project`. Can I just add a field through aggregation pipeline in such a way that I don't have to specified other field one by one, something like

```
db.people.aggregate([
     {$appendField: {birth_month: {$month: "$birthdate"}}}
])
```

Comment: in that case dont add 20+ field rather put that field in project which you dont want {$project: {name: 0}} in that case it will select all field other than name.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I want to preserve the original document with all of its fields intact, but with an additional field (birth_month)

Comment: .... and without having to write the other field names down in $project

Comment: Thanks, Yes, that is exactly what I want. unfortunately the OP doesn't approved it as answer so what should I do here? answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve this problem. Just read the old post here ([MongoDB $project: Retain previous pipeline fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497499/mongodb-project-retain-previous-pipeline-fields), Thanks to @Johnny HK). Here's my solution (mongo 2.6 or later):

```
db.people.aggregate([
  {$project: {doc: "$$ROOT", birth_month: {$month: "$birthdate"}}}
  {$group: {_id: "$doc.gender"} } <-- here you can use fields of the original doc via $doc
])
```