# How could I modify the returned record format

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got nested structure with `profile` field after aggregation,

I want to flatten the profile structure and only preserve the name field.

How could I do that in aggregation.

My aggregation query is similar to this one

```
  db.hitting_stats.aggregate(
    [
      {$lookup: {
          from: 'players', 
          localField: 'name', 
          foreignField: 'name',
          as: 'profile'
        }
      }
    ]
  );
```

A record format after joining aggregation

```
 {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('566d93bb5e428410e5a3354c'),
  "author_id"=>113536670874,
  ...
  "created_time"=>"2015-11-27T09:17:07+0000",
  "profile"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('566d93695e428410e5a33224'), "name"=>"DJ"}}
```

Expected format

```
 {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('566d93bb5e428410e5a3354c'),
  "author_id"=>113536670874,
  ...
  "created_time"=>"2015-11-27T09:17:07+0000",
  "name"=>"DJ"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), add it after `$lookup`

```
{$lookup: {
          from: 'players', 
          localField: 'name', 
          foreignField: 'name',
          as: 'profile'
        }
      },
{$project: {
           _id: '$_id', 
           author_id: 1, 
           created_time: 1, 
           name: '$profile.name'
         }
      }
```

As Blacks points out in the comments, the output `$loopup` is 'array', to be more precisely

```
"name": { 
     "$arrayElemAt": [
              { "$map": { 
                   "input": "$profile", 
                   "as": "el", 
                   "in": "$$el.name" 
                   }},0]
         }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, this solution definitely works. however, there are more than 10 fields from the hitting_stats collection and those fields are changeable. Is there any alternative to avoid specifying all the fields in projection operation?

Comment: @newBike,[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) could meet your requirement.

Comment: @newBike, here is one related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497499/mongodb-project-retain-previous-pipeline-fields?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @newBike Actually your source example is not really acurate since the output field of a `$lookup` will **always** be an "array". So even if it where a "one to one" result you would still get an array in response, making the correct singular projection `"name": { "$arrayElemAt": [{ "$map": { "input": "$profile", "as": "el", "in": "$$el.name" }},0] }` and so on for each field you wanted if you expected to reshape directly into the top level document. There is no magic for this since the aggregation pipline does not have a coded structure for "looped" conversions.