# Wrap all fields of MongoDB Document into a root/top level object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have two documents in a collection:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "name": "aaaa",
    "phone": 111
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "bbbb",
    "phone": 999
  }
]
```

I want to run an aggregation pipeline that will merge/wrap/combine ALL the fields into a top-level root object called `lead`. Without mentioning/hardcoding the field names in the query.

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "lead": {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "aaaa",
      "phone": 111
    }
  },
  {
    "lead": {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "bbbb",
      "phone": 999
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works with [`$replaceWith`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) stage to replace the input documents with new outputdocuments. To get each (original) document, you need to use the `$$ROOT` variable.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      "lead": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jSF_HzaqRYg)

Comment: Can also be achieved with `$project` but I'm not sure which one is efficient/recommend?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75945067/9486457

Comment: From my perspective, I think the performance is not much different. This `$replaceWith`  is an alternative to `$project` and consider as a *shortcut*.

Answer (score 0):

Got some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739662/9486457) and was able to achieve it using `$project`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      lead: "$$ROOT",
      _id: false
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mr4u5pgRDUV)

`$$ROOT` in MongoDB references the content of this document.